# Postgresql databse with duplicate rows keep only the rows with true

Tags: postgresql, duplicates

I've got three columns:
GroupID  ID  Yes/No/1

The database consists of rows with duplicate values for group (same group) I want to remove the duplicate groups and just have uniek group values. However I only want to keep te duplicate rows with Yes and remove the rest.

so:  if I have 100 rows with groupID 502  and there are 400 No's, 50 "1", and 50 Yes   I want to have 1 row with  groupID 502 and it should be yes.

PLease help

Comment: please include sample of your test table and your query

Answer (score 0):

Use DISTINCT ON to remove duplicate rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (GroupID) GroupID, column_3
FROM table_name
WHERE column_3 LIKE 'Yes';
```

Comment: Thx however this will also delete groups that are not duplicate with No